# Should I downgrade my Unity project to the latest LTS version?

Tags: unity, version-control

I created my Unity project with a 2020 version and now I'm using 2020.2.0f1. Recently, I realized that using the latest LTS version is the best choice for games that are in production or about to ship. I tried downgrading to the latest LTS (2019.4.18f1) but since Unity doesn't support downgrading, all my objects disappeared and I got a lot of weird errors in console. My question is:

Should I continue developing the game with the version that I'm using right now or downgrade to the latest LTS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LTS branches are mostly intended for people who started a long-term project on an older version of Unity and are now afraid of upgrading to a more recent version because it might break too many things.

So when you started your project on 2020.2, then you might want to stay on the 2020 branch and switch to the 2020 LTS branch as soon as it becomes available... or switch to 2021 depending on how well that upgrade goes.

Comment: 2021.1 just went in beta, so hopefully a 2020 LTS will come soon.